# Switch DbFunctions to a non-db implementation depending on context

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, expression

I have an expression that uses `DbFunctions` class to calculate dates. It works fine for `linq-to-entities` but I want to reuse this expression for non-db functionality. Is it possible to detect if expression is evaluated in db context or not and use corresponding implementation? I've seen solution for unit tests which involves mock objects but I need this expression in common business-logic so mocks don't look like a good solution.

Here is my expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> Expired(int expirationPeriod)
{
    return s => s.Status == Status.Created && DbFunctions.AddMinutes(s.UpdateDateUTC, expirationPeriod) < DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> Expired(int expirationPeriod)
{
    return s => s.Status == Status.Created && MyCustomResolver.AddMinutes(s.UpdateDateUTC, expirationPeriod) < DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

where `MyCustomResolver` will use either `DbFunctions` or `DateTime` implementation depending on context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the following approach:

1. Define a function with `DbFunction` attribute. This way it uses corresponding SQL function if used in Linq-to-Entities expression or C# function if executed in non-db context

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Utilize functions for both Linq-to-Entities and non-db context
   /// </summary>
   public static class MyCustomResolver
   {
       [DbFunction("Edm", "AddMinutes")]
       public static DateTime? AddMinutes(DateTime? timeValue, int addValue)
       {
           return timeValue?.AddMinutes(addValue);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Build expressions using helper function defined above

   ```
   public static Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> Expired(int expirationPeriod)
   {
       return s => s.Status == Status.Created && MyCustomResolver.AddMinutes(s.UpdateDateUTC, expirationPeriod) < DateTime.UtcNow;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ICustomResolver
{
    DateTime AddMinutes(DateTime, int);
}

public class DbCustomResolver : ICustomResolver
{
    public DateTime AddMinutes(DateTime time, int minutes)
    {
        return DbFunctions.AddMinutes(time, minutes);
    }
}

public class NonDbCustomResolver : ICustomResolver
{
    public DateTime AddMinutes(DateTime time, int minutes)
    {
        return time.AddMinutes(minutes);
    }
}


ICustomResolver MyCustomResolver = 
   amIUsingDB ? new DbCustomResolver() : new NonDbCustomResolver();
```

Now, I imagine one could make the determination on-the-fly inside `AddMinutes`, but WHY?  It's better to do the `if()` once rather that doing it every time.

Comment: The problem is that inside expression I don't have an information if it's called for db or not, so the question is how to detect the actual context (this `amIUsingDB` value) without explicitly passing it every time

Comment: As for "why", the actual expressions are more complicated and it looks like an overhead for me to write two separate implementations for db and non-db context every time, so I wonder if I can select the correct implementation of a particular methods (like `AddMinutes`) when an expression depending on the actual context.

Comment: @Random  Exactly -- to both comments.  That's why I moved the evaluation of `amIUsingDB ` *outside* of the function.  You set `MyCustomResolver ` to the resolver you need once at the point to know that info, and then never worry about it again.  Note that with this, the `Expired` method you give in your question works as you'd like.

Comment: But how to actually evaluate `amIUsingDB` value? Or it's not possible, and I have to explicitly set it before using an expression?

Comment: Well, you have to explicitly set `MyCustomResolver` to the proper object. How/when you do that it up to you.  **At some point in your code**, you know if you are using a db or not.  Set it then.